# How to display images via links in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, libreoffice-calc

I have a program that exports a CSV file that contains links to thumbnails in its cells and I am trying to find a way to display the thumbnails within the cells of the CSV file is a part of a row that contains data.

Is there maybe a different file format that would allow me to display the thumbnails via links? Or maybe there is a better way to resolve this Python.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: CSV files are text files, so can't contain graphics, so you need some other final output file format. Microsoft Excel does does support this, so you could use a third-party Python module that allows supports creating them, [XlxsWriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) is a popular one. With it, you can read the csv file and transform it into a `.xlxs` file (which LibreOffice can probably read).

Comment: Thanks for the help! That module is everything I needed. You can also see images in xlsx files in LibreOffice Calc (at least for me).